# Get sub-items by string instead of by index

Tags: c#, listview

I have a simple `ListView` with two columns: `ID | Name`

I would get ID and Name from selected row:

```cs
ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
MessageBox.Show(item.subItem[0].Text + " " + item.subItem[1].Text);
```

Is there any way to not get by numbers (0 or 1), but by nameColumn instead, similar to this `datareader` example?:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "select * from mytable;";
sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
// ...
string password = sqlite_datareader["password"].ToString();
```

I would get it this way for listView, details:

```
MessageBox.Show(item.subItem["ID"].Text + " " + item.subItem["Name"].Text);
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly as you have demonstrated but the string you use must be the value of the Name property of the corresponding ColumnHeader, not the Text.  It may well be that the Name and Text are the same but it's the Name that matters.

CORRECTION:  It's actually the Name of the ListViewSubItem that needs to be specified, not the Name of the corresponding ColumnHeader.

Comment: in my options for listview i have two columns:
text: ID, name: ID
text: Name, name: Name
You think about this?

Comment: My apologies.  I read the documentation incorrectly.  It's not the Name of the corresponding ColumnHeader but rather the Name of the ListViewSubItem itself.  It would make sense to use the Name or Text of the column as the Name of the subitem.

Comment: No problem :) Thanks you for spending time about my problem!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
       item.SubItems[listView1.Columns.IndexOf(ID)].Text
```

:-)